# Can I block certain users from showing in YouTube searches?

Tags: youtube

There are some uploaders that have nothing but spam related videos. Blocking them with the regular YouTube settings doesn't do this. I just want to search for product reviews without the spam.

Can I block certain users from showing in YouTube searches?

I'm open to 3rd party solutions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [YouTube Blocklist](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/101471) for greasemonkey to "Block annoying YouTube users from your search results and sidebar."